# Maven build Compilation error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Maven

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a maven project forked and cloned from a git repo onto my eclipse. It is build on Java 8. The first thing i do is perform a

```
mvn clean install
```

But I get following failure message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Maven ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Maven ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Maven ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 66 source files to /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/PrenPost/scanUtility.java:[54,52] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/AppUtility.java:[87,86] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/PrenPost/ComparisionUtility.java:[58,52] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.266 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-01T12:11:27+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Maven: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/PrenPost/scanUtility.java:[54,52] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/AppUtility.java:[87,86] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/PrenPost/ComparisionUtility.java:[58,52] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

However, below is the build path details of the project which clearly has JRE - 8 set up:
[image: build path]

and the compilation set up:

[image: Compliance level]

No matter how many times I build the project, i get the same error. Even after cleaning the project and refreshing it from eclipse doesn't help. Please guide.

**UPDATE:**

After adding the properties to set maven compiler plugin

```
<properties>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

,

am getting the below error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Maven ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Maven ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Maven ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 66 source files to /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java: /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 4 warnings 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java:[26,22] package com.apple.eawt does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java:[93,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Application
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java:[93,67] cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable Application
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.591 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-01T13:09:47+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/347M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Maven: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java:[26,22] package com.apple.eawt does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java:[93,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Application
[ERROR] /Users/vshukla/git/Prism/src/main/java/main/MainUITabbed.java:[93,67] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: variable Application
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And here is the code snippet giving the compilation error from MainUITabbed class:

```
    import com.apple.eawt.Application;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    
    
                    Application application = Application.getApplication(); // line 93
                
                    ImageIcon imgicon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                            "ICON.jpg"));
                    Image img = imgicon.getImage();
    
                    
                    application.setDockIconImage(img);
                    
                    MainUITabbed frame = new MainUITabbed();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the dependency:
`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.apple</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppleJavaExtensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>` in your pom.xml?

Comment: No. Let me try.

Comment: Brilliant. It worked. But how? Why was that error?

Comment: Because you were obviously using that library. For maven to know to add the classes in there to the classpath you have to define the dependencies accordingly.

Comment: What is AppleJavaExtensions here?Is that your java class name

Comment: @DrHopfen Chamzz.dot would like to ask you but forgot to address the question to you. Please answer to him!

Comment: @chamzz.dot In the snippet I posted above it ist the artifactId of a library provided by apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AppleJavaExtensions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000677-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 176):

The error occurred because the code is not for the default compiler used there. Paste this code in effective POM before the root element ends, after declaring dependencies, to change the compiler used. Adjust version as you need.

```
<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: also please make sure that eclipse.ini file has correct JRE version which you have set as project JDK

Comment: `source` and `target` are these JDK versions?

Comment: to upgrade to 3.6+ refer to the valid versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: addings this to my pom file worked for me... but I still don't really understand why. Using java 12, I am able to do clean package on my simple project via the command line. But when I try to do the same though maven, I get the error described in this post. When you say "the code is not for the default compiler used there", are you referring to the code of maven, or code in the project itself? I similarly have set my java compiler to version 12 in eclipse, so it should be using the same java version as far as I'm aware...

Answer (score 53):

I don't think that IDE is relevant here. After all you're running a Maven and Maven doesn't have a source that will allow to compile the diamond operators.
So, I think you should configure maven-compiler-plugin itself.

You can read about this [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html). But in general try to add the following properties:

```
<properties>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

and see whether it compiles now in Maven only.

Comment: This works perfectly. No need of anything else to be added to fix the error.

Comment: Yeah not relevant to IDE just add compiler as you mention its work only if we add manually.

Answer (score 12):

If your local jdk version is 11 or 9, 10, and your project's java source/target version is 1.8, and you are using `org.projectlombok:lombok` package, then you can try to update its version to 1.16.22 or 1.18.12, like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.22</version>
        </dependency>
```

It just solved my issue.

Comment: Solved my problem too. thanks

Comment: It worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You should add the code into pom.xml like:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Solved for me. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

make sure java home path is correct. for my case, java home path is wrong in pom file.

```
  <properties>
        <java.home>/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/javac</java.home>
  </properties>




              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                      <verbose>true</verbose>
                      <fork>true</fork>
                      <executable>${java.home}</executable>
                   <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

**This is an irritating error that pops up once in a while , jotting down some steps which help:**

*Writing answer from eclipse perspective as base logic will remain the
same whether done by Intellij or command line*

1. Rt click your project -> Maven -> Update project -> Select Force
   update -> Click OK
2. Under properties tag , add :

> ```
> <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> 
> <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
> ```

3. In some instances, you will start seeing error as we tried force update saying ,
   ***failure to transfer X dependency from Y path , resolutions will not
   be reattempted , bla bla bla***

   In such case quickly fix it by cd to .m2/repository folder and run following command :

> ```
> for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
> ```

Comment: This cmd will do what?

Comment: Yes , this command works , I had used it before putting this answer.

Answer (score 6):

## `<maven.compiler.release>` (not `source` & `target`)

Several of the other Answers show `<maven.compiler.source>` & `<maven.compiler.target>`. Both of these are now supplanted by the simpler single element: `<maven.compiler.release>`.

```xml
<maven.compiler.release>15</maven.compiler.release>
```

So this:

```xml
  <!--old-school-->
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

…becomes:

```xml
  <!--modern-->
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>15</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
```

See Question, [*“maven.compiler.release” as an replacement for source and target?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59049980/642706)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was caused from an incompatibility with OpenJDK 9 (which I haven't investigated).

If you don't need JDK 9, a temporary work-around would be to purge it from your machine:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-9-jdk openjdk-9-jre 
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-9-jdk-headless openjdk-9-jre-headless
```

Comment: Indeed this was the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Buddy,
If every this is up-to-date, even then you are having this problem, then 
try running this command from the terminal directly instead of running from eclipse.
`$ mvn clean install` 
and make sure these things:

- maven is in system path
- all maven dependencies are avaialble at `.m2/repository`
- java is in system path

Answer (score 4):

In case if you are able to compile `mvn compile` the project successful from terminal but not from Eclipse check out Window > Preferences >Installed JREs, make sure you have selected JRE that is under JDK (check out the paths of 2 different JRE's in pic), as Maven needs JDK to compile you need to add it.

[image: Installed JREs]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I Changed this

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
 </configuration>
```

here 1.7 is my JDK version.it was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the file location where the POM is stored and open cmd.
Then type "mvn --v" to check the maven version and java runtime provided.
Check runtime attribute and if it is "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191" or even close to a JRE, go to environment variables and add a new "system variable" called "JAVA_HOME" with a value "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191".

Reopen the cmd and then "clean install" the project.

Answer (score 2):

for it was comming because of java version mismatch ,so I have corrected it and i am able to build the war file.hope it will help someone

```
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in pom.xml file and after updating the project, the problem is gone.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

1. Update the pom.xml under `<plugin></plugin>`.
2. Update your project.
3. Then clean maven and install maven.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to run my own build on the other suggestions here. I even tried different versions of maven-compiler-plugin: 3.1, 3.7.0, etc.

I made it work adding this:

```
<testSourceDirectory>/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

I tried this approach because it seems like the /src/test/java directory is considered a java class that is why it is compiled the same time as /src/test/java. So my hunch were right in my case.

Maybe it is to others too, so just try this one.

Comment: it helped me in building the swagger plugin on windows 10 successfully

Answer (score 2):

My issues was that I was running `mvn compile` from a child project directory instead of the parent project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the solution was set JAVA_HOME in environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

Worked by adding this in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Even you have SDK 13 or 14.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Switch Project SDK & Project language level to Java version 1.8

Here is example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The below pom.xml configuration is making the build successful and make sure project buildpath JRE System library should point to Java8.

org.apache.maven.pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin3.7.0                    1.81.8

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. [How do I write a good answer? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Jdk 9 and 10 solution

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

and make sure your maven is pointing to JDK 10 or 9.
`mvn -v`

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T14:49:05-05:00)
Maven home: C:\devplay\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 10.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your pom.xml and do CTRL+S, it will automatically build the project.

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>3.5.1</version> 
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source> 
        <target>1.8</target> 
    </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Now click on Run as >Maven Test.

This error will definitely get solved.

Comment: <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart you IDE and exec mvn clean.
And setting jdk full path in maven.

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <JAVA_HOME>/home/jdk-17</JAVA_HOME>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it seemed to be all the answers on this page, plus the right JDK. I added the properties:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

and the JDK 1.8 plug-in pointing to my open JDK from Redhat:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>C:\java\java-1.8.0-openjdk\bin\javac.exe</executable>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and ran

```
mvn clean verify
```

and got build success. Yay.

Edit:
I think this is actually what made the difference: https://mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-ide-no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-rather-than-a-jdk/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set the JAVA_HOME correctly but still had problem for hours!
Finally I found out that I had settings.xml in .m2 directory and the java home was set there and pointed to another path. I ran the following command to find out what java path the maven is using:

```
mvn clean install -X | grep -i "executable"
```

Then I corrected the java home path in the settings.xml in .m2 directory and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you have your project under File->Project Structure setup for one specific version of Java and you have your Pom.xml setup for a different version of Java, you will get this error.   For example, running Java 8 under Project Structure and Java 11 in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve it manually many times, but every time error occurs in maven.

Last I left it to maven to solve this,

First use Maven clean,

```
Right-click on project -> Run as -> Maven Clean
```

Second use Maven Install,

```
Right-click on project -> Run as -> Maven Install
```

Third use Maven Update,

```
Right-click on project -> Maven -> Update Project
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java 11 this plugin should work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I had set the `<packaging>` to `war` instead of `jar`
in my pom.xml while using javafx.

```xml
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Answer (score 0):

That was really painful 2 hours...

Here's what worked for me (while creating a new project):

- Check what Java version you've got installed (I've used Java 11. Older versions may not be compatible with some Maven versions)
- Environment variables - check if you've got proper Java version applied
- Use https://start.spring.io/, instead of IntelliJ's initializator
- Name your project in "Artifact" field. Do not use any uppercase letters. Do not rename any other fields
  [image: spring.io]
- Do not rename a directory name of unpacked .zip file
- IntelliJ: Ctrl+Alt+S and check if you are using proper Java version
- If any changes applied -> Reload Maven -> Clean -> Install

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade your version of Maven, that's what fixed this for me.

```
export M2_HOME=/.../java/Maven/apache-maven-3.9.0
echo | mvn -v
```

Older versions of mvn don't work with later versions of java

Answer (score 0):

I solved with adding this to the active profile in settings.xml

```
<properties>
   <JAVA_1_8_HOME>c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\</JAVA_1_8_HOME>
</properties>
```