# how to setup maven setup for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm quite new to Jenkins setup. 
Using Eclipse,spring,maven project

Jenkins 의 Global Tool Configuration 에서

NAME: MAVEN_HOME

install from apache 3.6.0

error is following

> [INFO] Copying 19 resources
>
> [INFO]
>
> ### [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ egov
>
> [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
>
> [INFO] Compiling 15 source files to
>   C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\TestJob1\target\classes
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Total time:  2.154 s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-01T01:44:07Z
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project egov: Fatal error compiling:
>   CompilerException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>
> Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven build Compilation error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525139/maven-build-compilation-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

In your pipeline (which you should post) run a maven --version and make sure the JRE that is running Maven is also a JDK.

Also, it looks like your Jenkins is running as an administrator.  That's not a good idea because the jobs (pipelines) will have admin access to the host.