# "maven.compiler.release" as an replacement for source and target?

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have two questions about `maven.compiler.release`-tag

I want to replace

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

to

```
<properties>
     <maven.compiler.release>12</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

**If I use `<maven.compiler.release>`-property, do I have to set the release tag also in the plugin?**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- do I need that ? -->
        <release>12</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

According to https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version, it is set to both.

If I use `maven.compiler.release` instead of `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target`, then `-bootclasspath` is also set and will do a cross-compile. **What does this mean? Will the compilation file sizes with set `-bootclasspath` be bigger or will the compilation need more time?**

Comment: Simply the property `<maven.compiler.release>12</maven.compiler.release>` is sufficient. And you don't need to set also the configuration for maven-compiler-plugin. The configuration for release tag is automatically picked up. The bootclasspath part is automatically done by using the `--release` option. The size of files is not related to that...So simple suggestions use `release` part for JDK9+ otherwise source/target...

Comment: @khmarbaise Way not make an Answer of your Comment? That we can give some up-votes, and also mark this Question as resolved.

Comment: Related: [*Specifying java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38882080/642706)

Comment: Note, that correct release version in your example is "12", not "1.12".

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The "simple suggestion" in the other answer won't work correctly because unfortunately the situation is not simple. The compiler options mean slightly different things. The `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` options refer to the source code format and the format of the generated class files, respectively. But they do *not* take into account API changes as `maven.compiler.release` does.

So if you blindly just use `<maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>` and `<maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>`, if you build using Java 11 for example the generated class files will support Java 8 but the API may still rely on Java 11 changes and break when run on Java 8. See [How should javac 11 link methods overridden in later versions with a Java 8 target?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64868952) for more discussion.

The solution is not so simple if you want to designate Java 8 but build on Java 9+. You'll need to specify the source and target as you are doing, using compiler options supported by Java 8:

```xml
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Then you'll need to set up a separate profile in the `<profiles>` section that is only activated in Java 9+ to turn on the `maven.compiler.release` option:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>java-8-api</id>
  <activation>
    <jdk>[9,)</jdk>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

That way if you build on Java 9+, `maven.compiler.release` will come into effect and restrict the API to be compatible with Java 8. If you build on Java 8, the other two options will set the source code and class file format to Java 8, and the API will be Java 8 compatible by definition.

The better option for everyone involved of course is just to move to Java 11 as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi,
can't we just add the 3 properties without setting up a profile ?
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
(I edited my comment : I think source and target should be set to '1.8' and not '8')

Comment: No, I don't believe that is possible, because the Java 8 compiler would complain that it doesn't understand the "source" option. Try it and let me know what it does.

Comment: for JDK >= 9 + Maven you can have them all. Obviously the `maven-compiler-plugin` suppresses the redundant options, because with `javac`on the command line you'll get: 
error: option -source cannot be used together with --release
error: option -target cannot be used together with --release

Comment: for JDK <= 8 the build with <maven.compiler.release> would fail: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release

Answer (score 12):

Simply the property `<maven.compiler.release>12</maven.compiler.release>` is sufficient. And you don't need to set also the configuration for maven-compiler-plugin. The configuration for release tag is automatically picked up.
The bootclasspath part is automatically done by using the `--release` option. The size of files is not related to that...

So simple suggestions use `release` part for JDK9+ otherwise source/target...

Comment: downvote due to no linked reference to back up the answer.  Should this be the accepted answer?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html, search for <release>