# Eclipse, Maven: Modules are not supported in -source 8 (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)

Tags: java, git, eclipse, maven

I am new with Eclipse and Maven and when I'm trying to run this project here

```
https://github.com/klevis/DigitRecognizer
```

The Java JDK version installed in my system is 14

```
java --version
java 14.0.2 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

while installing the Pom.xml file in the Eclipse using Maven Install, it is giving me the below error log and this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project DigitRecognizer: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/nitisht/git/DigitRecognizer/src/main/java/module-info.java:[1,1] modules are not supported in -source 8
[ERROR]   (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/nitisht/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/nitisht/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for ramo.klevis.ml:DigitRecognizer:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for junit:junit:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated) @ line 88, column 22
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 152, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< ramo.klevis.ml:DigitRecognizer >-------------------
[INFO] Building DigitRecognizer 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ DigitRecognizer ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 40 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ DigitRecognizer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to /Users/nitisht/git/DigitRecognizer/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/nitisht/git/DigitRecognizer/src/main/java/module-info.java:[1,1] modules are not supported in -source 8
  (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.810 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-04T15:36:19-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project DigitRecognizer: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/nitisht/git/DigitRecognizer/src/main/java/module-info.java:[1,1] modules are not supported in -source 8
[ERROR]   (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

POM FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ramo.klevis.ml</groupId>
    <artifactId>DigitRecognizer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.16</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>2.8.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>a</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!--    <repositories>
            <repository><id>a</id><url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10</url></repository>
        </repositories>-->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--LOGGER-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-ext -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Binding for Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j API and Core implementation required for binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.glazedlists</groupId>
            <artifactId>glazedlists_java16</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mortennobel/java-image-scaling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mortennobel</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-image-scaling</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-7.5</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-zoo</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>ramo.klevis.Run</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ramo.klevis.Run</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>


</project>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the pom.xml for the below plugin definition. As the error states, modules are not supported in version 8 of java. you need to update the versions below to the version you need.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> 
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Note that generally with 9+ `release` is the preferred tag (and the source/target/release combination has caused no end of glitches with various tooling interpreting differently).

Comment: <configuration> <source>11</source> <target>11</target> </configuration>. it should be in that format.

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049980/maven-compiler-release-as-an-replacement-for-source-and-target for more information on the release tag suggested by @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic

Comment: I did that, and the latest error is coming something like 

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project DigitRecognizer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/nitisht/git/DigitRecognizer/src/main/java/ramo/klevis/nn/NeuralNetwork.java:[7,42] package org.apache.spark.ml.classification does not exist

- but for like 100 of files..

Comment: Try a clean install first. Resolve any dependency issues you see.

Comment: You also could use `-Dmaven.compiler.target=1.8` and `-Dmaven.compiler.source=1.8` accordingly. Btw: Update to newest compiler-plugin might bring newer default-values. You could skip the configuration Adarsh suggested by using compiler-plugin-version `3.11.0` what automatically have `1.8` by default.