# VS Code, Java, Maven, "Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above"

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

When I load my Maven, Java project in Visual Studio Code, I get this error:

```
Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above Java(1610613381)
```

However, my `pom.xml` has my Java source level set to level 1.8 or above. For example:

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

And `mvn compile` works just fine.

What is going on?

Comment: I would suggest to use `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` instead of source/target... etc...

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks for that pointer. I agree, having just read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65655542/167920).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was using VS Code to open a *parent* folder of my Java project. That is, my `pom.xml` file was not in the folder that was opened by Visual Studio Code -- it was in the child folder which contained my Java project. When I *instead* open the Java project folder, the editor does not complain.

Comment: There must be more going on than I understand. Today, I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)