# How to see project JDK version in Eclipse using m2e

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse EE 2023-09 RC1 on Windows 10 with a Maven project imported using m2e. How can I easily check to see what JDK version Eclipse+m2e is using for a particular project?

I know that if I run a JUnit unit test e.g. `MyTest` using `Ctrl+F11`, Eclipse will create a run configuration for that unit test class. If I then edit that new run configuration, I can see under the "JRE" tab which JDK version the project is using by looking at the "Project execution environment". But surely there is an easier way.

I've looked under the obvious project properties (`Alt+Enter` in Project Explorer, or right-click on the project and and select "Properties"), but I see nothing about the Java version the project is using. I don't necessarily want to change it—there are just times I want to quickly confirm what it is. Am I missing it somewhere?

Comment: Typically the JDK compiler level of a maven project is set by the `pom` and the `maven.compiler.target` and `maven.compiler.source` properties.

Comment: Yes, I know what specifies it in the POM. (And in fact you are only half-right in your description of setting the JDK version in the POM; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65655542). And I know what the JDK version _should_ be set to. This question is asking how to verify what the JDK version _actually is set to_ in Eclipse for a particular project.

Comment: `System.out.printf("Vendor: %s, Version: %s%n", System.getProperty("java.vendor"), System.getProperty("java.version"));`

Comment: The JRE that you're *compiling* against will be part of the Build Path, usually visible in the Package and Project Explorers if you start expanding the structure under the project. The one you're *running* with is going to vary with the Run Configuration. They don't have to be the same. Maybe you don't want them to be, who knows.