# VSCode Unbound classpath container JRE System Library [JavaSE-15]

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have been programming a java project using JDK14 and VSCode. Recently JDK15 is available, and I switched to the JDK. As for configuration, I pointed the VScode `java.home` and system `JAVA_HOME` to the new JDK folder.

When I clear the VSCode cache and restart the IDE, I started receiving this error

```
{
"resource": "/E:/dev/java/challenges/",
"owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
"code": "963",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-15]' in project 'challenges'",
"source": "Java",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 1
}
```

I have seen similar questions/answers, but none of them was directed to VSCode.

[image: Screen shot on the error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [VsCode-Java in Twitter](https://twitter.com/VSCodeJava/status/1306275380584763392), JDK15 support won't be released until the end of September, and here is a [github issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1627) that's related to Java 15 not support.

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42525941/1005462
this one was helpfull;

replace :
build block in POM to

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: this worked for me. thanks. But can you tell me why the built in template doesn't work?

Comment: maybe new java features not added to vscode yet

Answer (score 2):

I am new to building Java apps in VSCode. In my case, I was developing a microservice using Spring Boot. Here is what I've done to solve the issue ;

1. Make sure `JAVA_HOME` env variable is registered to the right path
2. Configured JDK path in `java.jdt.ls.java.home` to settings.json located inside .vscode. Here is my configuration.

```
{
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.compile.nullAnalysis.mode": "automatic",
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home"
}
```

3. Restart the VSCode

Comment: In my case on WIndows 10 machine this was: 

"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-21"